# How to remove Samsung refrigerator touch screen?

Tags: refrigerator, samsung

I have a Samsung french door refrigerator (RF28K9380SG). It is displaying a `PC Ch` error. I'd like to remove the touch screen to check that the connections are good, and possibly replace it. Does anyone know how to remove the touch screen? I couldn't find any instructions online.

[image: Refrigerator display]

Comment: Google found this easy.  https://www.hunker.com/13410015/how-to-remove-the-display-panel-on-a-samsung-french-door-refrigerator.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before posting, but my display panel doesn't have two slots for a flathead screw driver.

Comment: according to this: https://homesteady.com/how-8530377-remove-panel-kenmore-elite-refrigerator.html some don't have screws, just clips and possibly glue holding the display. If there are no screws, it suggests just starting to pry off the panel with a putty knife.

Comment: Do Samsung's docs indicate that the `PC Ch` error code points to bad connections on the panel or that it's a failing panel? (Never hurts to ask the obvious...)